# Kotlin - Using Enums to retrieve a Char

Tags: enums, kotlin

Being a little new to OOP concepts, enums in Kotlin are a bit confusing to me. My caveman interpretation is that enums are used to store non changing variables. I'm making a simple Tic-Tac-Toe app and simply want to store the values 'X', 'Y', and '-' all as Chars. Where is my confusion? Is there a better way to retrieve a particular set of Chars from a "library"? Here is my current assumption in code:

```
    enum class markers(char: Char){
            X('X'), O('O'), EMPTY('-')
        }

//To access the enums, thought it would be something like this

        fun printX(){
            println(markers.X)
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to have the property `char` instead of the enum constants‘ name, change to:

```
    fun printX(){
        println(markers.X.char)
    }
```

Also make `char` a `val` so that it’s accessible as a property: `enum class markers(val char: Char)`

Comment: You should probably point out this will require making the `char` a `val`

Comment: Thank you for going the distance and pointing out how to correctly use enum member names to point to a value, which was the intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum class markers(private val char: Char){
        X('X'), O('O'), EMPTY('-');
override fun toString() = char.toString()
}

markers.values().forEach(::print)
```